# time in actions on google doesn't match my local time

Tags: node.js, datetime, actions-on-google

I'm trying to develop google assistant using node.js firebase cloud functions and Dialogflow
so when I was trying console.log to test what it looks like when I deploy everything works just fine but when I test it on a simulator the time in the sentence doesn't match my local time ex. it says it's 11:00 AM while in my country it's 18:00. can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Cloud Functions for Firebase, the webhook time is going to be set to the GMT timezone (+0). This is useful in some cases for consistency, with the downside that it won't guarantee to reflect the client.

In our [recently published location sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-location-nodejs) we use a new `timezone` field in order to get the client timezone. With this, and the timezone in GMT, you can use a library like [spacetime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spacetime) to get the time local to the user.

```js
const spacetime = require('spacetime');

app.handle('location_granted', (conv) => {
  const {id} = conv.request.device.timeZone;
  let localTime = spacetime(new Date());
  localTime = localTime.goto(id); // Set timezone

  conv.add(`The Local Time is ${localTime.format('{time}')}.`)
});
```

Comment: Sir, I got undefined on location

Comment: But do you get an undefined in the timezone field specifically?

Comment: I actually use app as an instance of Dialogflow so it didn't provide me timezone or if I miss it I'm sorry but I didn't find it , there is no way to get through this? (sigh)

Comment: Is it possible for you to migrate to Actions Builder?

Comment: You'll need to migrate the code, but it is largely a minimal refactor.

Comment: I will note Actions Builder only works with Assistant, so if you are using Dialogflow with other integrations you may not want to do this.